# Unexpected result due to injecting service into service Angular 6

Tags: javascript, angular, ngrx, angular6

I am using ngrx-store and Angular 6 in my project. Unfortunately, I can't reproduce my issue ob the [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-bh1yau?file=src%2Fapp%2Fservice1.ts), but i will describe my problem. I have `Service1` that is used in the component and also `Service2`, which is used inside `Service1`. `Service1` have few default properties that i am assigning before contstructor in it. So in my component on `ngOnInit` i make:

```
ngOnInit() {
  this.service1.init(someData);
}
```

After this in effects i make:

```
 @Effect({
    dispatch: false
  })
  addItem$ = this.actions$.pipe(
    ofType(fromReducers.AddItem),
    map((action: AddItem) => action.payload),
    tap(item=> *debugger* this.service2.addItemToService1(item))
  );
```

The problem is that at the *debugger* point if i look into `this.service2` it has inside `service1`, because i am injected it there via DI, but `this.service2.service1.items` is empty array. It seems like `service1` creates new instance of itself inside `service2`. I expect that there should be data that i passes earlier in `ngOnInit` (`someData`).
As you can see in the stackbltiz link services are `providedIn: 'root'`.

What i am doing wrong?

Comment: If you can't reproduce it on stackblitz then maybe you can create minimal reproduction and provide link to github project?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, I found what was the problem. My Service1 was located into a separate module. And into this module, I had `providers: [Service1]`. So the service was creating two times instead of one. So removing in from providers declaration solved the problem